# Java Entryset Error

Tags: java

I am having below error for this code,

Type mismatch: **cannot convert from** `Set<Map.Entry<Date,List<Transaction>>> to Set<Date>`

Code:

```
final Map<Date, List<Transaction>> transactionsMap= new HashMap<Date, List<Transaction>>();

Set<Date> set = transactionsMap.entrySet(); //Error line
```

What is this error? how to resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [`keySet()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#keySet%28%29) to get the set of key values. [`entrySet()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet%28%29) returns the set of [entries](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html) (i.e. key **and** value combined).

```
Map<Date, List<Transaction>> transactionsMap= new HashMap<Date, List<Transaction>>();
Set<Date> set = transactionsMap.keySet();
```

If, however, you want to use the `entrySet()` method, then you'll need to use the appropriate type for your variable:

```
Set<Map.Entry<Date, List<Transaction>> entries = transactionMap.entrySet();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I have to use entrySet instead of keySet for performance issue.